# Different Periods Average in Power BI

Tags: powerbi, dax, measure

Here is my data

**Finance**

[image]

I have chart that display monthly data

Like this

[image]

I need to do **average** for periods that are specified in another table.

**Periods**

[image]

So the end results should look like this

[image]

I know it should be a **New Measure**, but not sure how to write the DAX for that measure to do this **averaging**

I tried and ended with this, but it is not working

```
CALCULATE (
Average(Finance[Result]),
FILTER (
ALL ( Periods),
DATE ( Finance[Year], Finance[Month], 1 ) >= Periods[FromDate] 
&&  DATE ( Finance[Year], Finance[Month], 1 ) < Periods[ToDate]
)
)
```

but this is does not work

Anyone know how to build the **measure dax** to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in your place i would add a column in finance table which contains the period values too...

Comment: ok, what is next after having period values in finance table?

Comment: use that column as axis values and drill down... you should have your desired result.